# Is $\mathcal{F}$ (an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{1, 3, 5\} \in \mathcal{F}$) a non-principle/free filter?

Tags: filters

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dotsc\}$ such that $\{1, 3, 5\} \in \mathcal{F}$. Can we find out whether $\mathcal{F}$ is a principle or non-principle filter? I was thinking that $\mathcal{F}$ is a non-principle filter on $\mathbb{N}$ because it contains Fréchet filter. So I tried to show that.

Let $E$ be the set of even number and $O := \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \ \text{is odd and } n >5\}$. Then $\{1,3, 5\} = \mathbb{N}\backslash(E \cup O)$. But we still need to show whether $E \cup O \in \mathcal{F}$ right? Or maybe it is undecidable that $\mathcal{F}$ is principle or non-principle filter on $\mathbb{N}$.

Can anyone please confirm whether I can decide that $\mathcal{F}$ is principle or not? (an explanation would also be appreciated)

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320561/non-principal-ultrafilter-containing-a-finite-set) help?

Comment: @Matematleta So I suppose the answer to my question is no. Because $\mathcal{F}$ has a finite set and it is proven that $\mathcal{F}$ should be principle. Right?